# Pipe Notifications bind failure "Integration cannot be null for Azure."

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting error as `Pipe Notifications bind failure "Integration cannot be null for Azure."` while trying to configure `snowpipe` in `Snowflake`

```
  create or replace pipe snowpipe_db.public.mypipe auto_ingest=true as
  copy into snowpipe_db.public.mytable
  from @snowpipe_db.public.mystage
  file_format = (type = 'JSON');
```

Do we need to set any additional parameter for `Snowpipe`?

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? I am trying to ingest from s3 and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh yes.. Its not at all easy to connect Azure and Snowpipe. 
There are a lot of things that you need to configure before you run this command.

Go to the below link and click on the Azure BLOB option. 
Follow each and every step and you MAY be lucky enough to create your snowpipe.

I faced a lot of issues while doing the same!

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe.html

Comment: Thank you very much, Can you address what might be the reason for titled error, It seems I configured everything right.

Comment: You already configured everything thats mentioned in the link?

I cant recollect exactly but I think even i got the same error, even after all the configurations.